# jQuery each() not continuing code execution for first element if a second element was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if the title is not clear enough, I have `<a>` elements with the same class when user clicks on each one the jquery code should run for each one alone, the problem is when clicking the first element and before it finishes running the whole code if I click a second  element it leaves the first one incomplete and runs the code on the second one, it's supposed to work simultaneously (btw it's supposed to send data to a php file and it's working fine even if I click many elements by the classes are not working)

here's the code:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.anchor-tag-class').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                var id = $this.attr('data-id');
                if ( $this.hasClass('on') ) {
                    $this.removeClass('on');
                    $this.addClass('loading');
                    $.post("process.php", { element_id: id, status: 'off' }, function(data) { $this.addClass('off').removeClass('loading'); } );
                } else {
                    $this.removeClass('off');
                    $this.addClass('loading');
                    $.post("process.php", { element_id: id, status: 'on' }, function(data) { $this.addClass('on').removeClass('loading'); } );
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

so what am I doing wrong ?

and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `each()` in this case, as the code will only be run for the specific element which raised the event. You can also chain your functions hanging off the `$this` variable.

Try this:

```
$('.anchor-tag-class').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('data-id');
    if ( $this.hasClass('on') ) {
        $this.removeClass('on').addClass('loading');
        $.post("process.php", { element_id: id, status: 'off' }, function(data) { $this.addClass('off').removeClass('loading'); } );
    } 
    else {
        $this.removeClass('off').addClass('loading');
        $.post("process.php", { element_id: id, status: 'on' }, function(data) { $this.addClass('on').removeClass('loading'); } );
    }
});
```

Comment: Note, I added `var` before the `$this` declaration to make sure it still has scope within your `$.post` callbacks.

Comment: I'm not using the console, and thank you for cleaning up the code.
the functionality is working fine as I said but the problem when clicking another element and the first on still has the loading class, the function(data) { $this.addClass('off').removeClass('loading'); } in the $.post() won't run for that element

Comment: when I added var before $this it works now, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a $this variable, set to $(this)... Where is $this defined? If it is outside the scope of the function, that's your problem!